# jPaginate - Current page is showing page 1 even though you are on page 2

Tags: jquery

I am using jPaginate plugin (jquery).. The plugin is working for the most part except when a user clicks on page 2 for example.. the page that is shown is actually page 2 but on the pagination plugin.. *Page 1* is highlighted as the current page.

I need to fix that.. Any Ideas?

Comment: please provide some sample code

Comment: I actually got this figured out now.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to determine the current page number... I used the code below to do so:

```
<? 
$page = (isset($_REQUEST["page"])) ? $_REQUEST["page"] : 0;
$page = ($page > 0) ? $page - 1 : $page;
if ($page < 0){
header("location: /bumper-stickers.html");
?>
```

jQuery:

```
                            $("#demo2").paginate({
                            count         : a,
                            start         : '<?=intval($page + 1);?>',
                            display     : 10,
                            border                    : false,
                            text_color              : '#888',
                            background_color        : '#EEE',    
                            text_hover_color          : 'black',
                            cookies : true,
```